# how to modify values on specific dask dataframe partiton?

Tags: python, dask

**what I can do now as below:**

```
for i in range(10):                
　　　newddf[i] = ddf.get_partition(i).assign(xdate=20180620+i)
```

Is there any smart way to get current partition number and make it as a condition to code func when use `map_partitions(func, *args, **kwargs)`?

**what I want is:**
different partition  assign different value

Comment: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3707